# Accepting my answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

what happens when I accept answer posted by me?

Answer (score 11):

The answer will be checked as the accepted answer as it normally would.

The differences are:

- It will not be pinned to the top when sorting
- You won't get the +2 reputation for accepting it
- Nor will you get the +15 for having the accepted answer.

It's quite OK to accept your own answer.